# Simple Login with OO-PHP

Tags: php, syntax-error

I'm trying just to validate, on submitting the form that the `username` and `password` aren't empty.

**Form**:

```
<form action="usercheck.php" method="post">
    User: <input type="text" name="username" maxlength="10" />
    Pass: <input type="password" name="password" maxlength="10" />      
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

**usercheck.php**

```
<?php

class Vuln{
    
    public $username = $_POST['username'];
    public $password = $_POST['password'];
    
    public function ShowErrors(){
        if($this->username == '' || $this->password == ''){
            return 'username or password field blank';  
        }
        else{
            echo stripslashes('we\'re good');
        }   
    }
    
    $entered = new Vuln;
    echo $entered->ShowErrors();
    
}


?>
```

When I test, it says:

> **Parse error:** syntax error, unexpected `T_VARIABLE`, expecting `T_FUNCTION` on line :
>
> ```
>     $entered = new Vuln;
> ```

Comment: why not just `echo "we're good"`?

Comment: Should use `bcrypt`, rule of thumb at this point in the game ;) (just a suggestion)

Comment: @bigman: He hasn't done anything with them yet. He didn't even process them, not to mention save them to a database. Hashing is still several steps away for him at this point ;)

Comment: @MarcB - I wonder how this provides value as a response. --bigman - I'm not even onto hashing or cryptography yet, but thanks :)

Comment: @code: hence it being a comment, not an answer.

Comment: lol, I even wrapped it in parenthesis stating just a suggestion and I still get two responses like I did something wrong, lol

Comment: @bigman: this wasn't the case. But on SO mostly likey you will get uppish statements (sadly)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't have code inside a class definition like that

```
    class Vuln {
       //> Your class definition
    }

    //> Outside of the class

    $entered = new Vuln;
    echo $entered->ShowErrors();
```

I strongly suggest you to read all the basics from [PHP Doc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/oop5.intro.php)

Comment: Good suggestion here. Thanks Yes123

Answer (score 1):

Part of your code is placed directly in the class:

```
$entered = new Vuln;
echo $entered->ShowErrors();
```

Those should be placed outside the class definition. As mentioned below, change:

```
public $username = $_POST['username'];
public $password = $_POST['password'];
```

to

```
public $username;
public $password;
```

and initiate variables in constructor or outside the class.

Comment: You're on the right track, but you missed that the references to $_POST also have to be moved into the constructor

Comment: Correct you are, my friend, overlooked that one.

Answer (score 0):

something like

```
$entered = new Vuln;
$entered->username = $_POST['username'];
$entered->password = $_POST['password'];
$entered->ShowErrors();
```

you are currently instantiating your class from within your class.

edit: added for more clarification -
this instantiates the class and should be outside the class.  remove the instantiation that is within the class.

another edit changed the variable name to match example

Comment: How can I add checking for empty string? Does this all above go outside of the class?

Comment: yes that is all outside of your class, you see the last line calls the function in your class that does your work

Comment: if you want some work done at the time of instantiation you can add a constructor function.  http://php.net gives better general examples than I can.  This is specific to your example.

Answer (score 0):

The code for execution of an **object** shouldn't be found inside of the **class definition**.

You probably meant this:

```
<?php

class Vuln{

    public $username = $_POST['username'];
    public $password = $_POST['password'];

    public function ShowErrors(){
        if($this->username == '' || $this->password == ''){
            return 'username or password field blank';  
        }
        else{
            echo stripslashes('we\'re good');
        }   
    }


}

$entered = new Vuln;
echo $entered->ShowErrors();
```

Comment: This is what I mean't, but it is showing an error of syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE for line  public $username = $_POST['username'];   any clue why ?

Comment: Right, I didn't notice. You can't have dynamic values as the default variable value. Have a constructor function (`public function __construct()`) which initializes those variables.

Answer (score 0):

Whats stopping you using

```
<form action="usercheck()" id="form" method="post">
```

and using the following JS

```
var theForm = document.forms["form"];
var user = theForm.elements["user"];
var pass = theForm.elements["pass"];

if(user.value==null || user.value=="")
{
alert("First name(s) must be filled out");
return false;
}

else if(pass.value==null || pass.value=="")
{
    alert("Last name must be filled out");
return false;
}

else
{
return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't create object of the class from within the class itself. You must call the class when the form is submitted. Also change the class filename to something like vuln.php and update the usercheck.php to the following code.

```
     if($_POST){
        include("Vuln.php");
        $entered = new Vuln;
        echo $entered->ShowErrors();
     }
```

Hope it may help you.